# Reaction Roles on Discord.Net Embed from Command

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

**i want to add reaction roles to an Embed thats created by a command.**

I know when i make an auto post for reaction roles it uses the client.ReactionAdded  but when adding it to my Program.cs and using ISocketMessageChannel its an error and dont work.

My command create an embed and adds a thumbs up emoji, i want to set the user a role when hitting the thumbs up emoji

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Net;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace CentricXBot.Modules.Fun
{
    // for commands to be available, and have the Context passed to them, we must inherit ModuleBase
    public class Test : ModuleBase
    {
        [Command("test")]
        public async Task TestComand()
        
        {
            var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                {
                    Title = "TestEmbed",
                    Description = "Test",
                                
                }.Build();

                var myReaction = new Emoji("");

                var msg =  await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embed);
                msg.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji(""));
               
        }
    }
}
```

Ok im quite unclear sry for this.. i have this structure

````
        {
            
                
            // call ConfigureServices to create the ServiceCollection/Provider for passing around the services
            using (var services = ConfigureServices())
            {
                // get the client and assign to client 
                // you get the services via GetRequiredService<T>
                var client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();
                _client = client;



                // setup logging and the ready event
                services.GetRequiredService<LoggingService>();

                services.GetRequiredService<TwitchHandler>();

                // this is where we get the Token value from the configuration file, and start the bot
                await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _config["token"]);
                await client.StartAsync();
                await client.SetGameAsync("LPDaVinci auf Twitch", "https://twitch.tv/lpdavinci", ActivityType.Streaming);
                
                client.ReactionAdded += ReactionAdded_Event; //No overload its underscored
                
                // we get the CommandHandler class here and call the InitializeAsync method to start things up for the CommandHandler service
                await services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandler>().InitializeAsync();

                await Task.Delay(-1);
            }
        }
        public void ReactionAdded_Event(Cacheable<IUserMessage, UInt64> message, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)
    {
        // idk how to get the cached embed message to get this triggered
    }```

i tried adding the client.ReactionAdded  but it cannot get the msg,
MessageCacheSize = 1000, is activated but i dont know how to get the embed Message posted by command for the reaction role
````

Comment: You should show the code that isn't working instead of the part that is. `but when adding it to my Program.cs and using ISocketMessageChannel its an error and dont work.` - What error?

Comment: Added some more description im kinda to dumb i guess.. to get the cached message and in my main.cs file the client.reactionadded is not working and underscored cuz of the ISOcketMessageChannel when replace it with IMessageChannel its not underscored but it wont get the reaction..

Comment: `public void ReactionAdded_Event(Cacheable<IUserMessage, UInt64> message, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)` -- your first parameter a `Cacheable` user message which has a `GetOrDownloadAsync` method. `var msg = await message.GetOrDownloadAsync();`

Comment: thank you alot now i have adding the Task to my commandhandler because the Program.cs is not working but the handler is loading anyway. i could try to make a reactionHandler. he gets cached messages as well. now the question when i have more embeds with thumb up emoji i need to make sure that the message is from . should i use for each other reaction role stuff other emojis or is there a id getter from the stored messages so make sure thumb1 is for message 1 and thumbup 2 is for message 2. this would be the last thing thank you so much anu6is are you on the discord api dc?

Comment: or message.contains for embeds that are created or check if the message is an embed which contains smthg.

Comment: All messages have an Id property. It's up to you to keep track of what Id belongs to which reaction message. When u send a message, the message object is returned, store the id from that returned message somewhere. When you get a reaction, check to see if the message id matches your stored message id.

Comment: got ya thank you again for your awesome help :)

Answer (score 0):

this is my code so far that do what i wanted, message storing and getting the ID is not finished yet and i need to get the ID other than now.  if using embeds message.id is the only way.. otherwise i could use msg.content.contains("string")  for embeds i need to work with message.id  but getting it is manually.. if someone knows how to do it better feel free to contact me :) thanks to Anu6is again

```
public async Task ReactionAdd(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> message, Cacheable<IMessageChannel, ulong> channel, SocketReaction reaction)
    {
        if (_client.GetUser(reaction.UserId).IsBot) return;
        var msg = await message.GetOrDownloadAsync();

            if (msg.Id.Equals(960529258160214036)){

            
            if (reaction.Emote.Name != "") return;
            await (reaction.User.Value as SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(913407637075394590);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Rolle [{(reaction.User.Value as SocketGuildUser).Guild.GetRole(913407637075394590)}] hinzugefügt für [{reaction.User}]");
       }
       

    }

    public async Task ReactionRemove(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> message, Cacheable<IMessageChannel, ulong> channel, SocketReaction reaction)
    {
        if (_client.GetUser(reaction.UserId).IsBot) return;
        var msg = await message.GetOrDownloadAsync();

            if (msg.Id.Equals(960529258160214036)){

            
            if (reaction.Emote.Name != "") return;
            await (reaction.User.Value as SocketGuildUser).RemoveRoleAsync(913407637075394590);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Rolle [{(reaction.User.Value as SocketGuildUser).Guild.GetRole(913407637075394590)}] entfernt für [{reaction.User}]");

       }
    }
```